# Is there a way to rewrite this statement without sub queries?

Tags: sql

I am trying to combine 4 queries for a monthly report so that I don't have to run them seperately. Our internal accounting software appears doesn't support sub queries so this statement doesn't work.

```
select left(salesgroupcode,4) as "Sales Group",
       count(Number_of_products),
       count(Number_of_discontinued),
       count(Number_not_uploaded),
       count(Number_sitting)
from (select
       case when quantityavailable > 1 then 1 end Number_of_products,
       case when quantityavailable > 1 and discontinued = true then 1 end Number_of_discontinued,
       case when quantityavailable > 1 and z_datefirstuploaded is null then 1 end Number_not_uploaded,
       case when quantityavailable > 1 and z_datefirstuploaded is null and dateoflastsale <= '01/01/2019' then 1 end Number_sitting
     from icprod
 ) icprod
```

I don't have any other info about the specific rules etc that the software allows so I'm happy to try anything.

Thanks in advance.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: There is only a single query in your question not 4 (and technically no sub-query either - that's called a "derived table")

Comment: Where does salesgroupcode come from? (It's not from the derived table...)

Comment: thanks for the info, the below solution worked. Salesgroupcode was from the icprod table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
select left(salesgroupcode,4) as "Sales Group",
       count(*),
       count(case when discontinued = true then 1 end ),
       count(case when z_datefirstuploaded is null then 1 end),
       count(case when z_datefirstuploaded is null and dateoflastsale <= '01/01/2019')
from icprod
where quantityavailable > 1
group by left(salesgroupcode,4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when quantityavailable > 1 then 1 else 0 end ) as Number_of_products,
       sum(case when quantityavailable > 1 and discontinued = true then 1 else 0 end) as Number_of_discontinued,
       sum(case when quantityavailable > 1 and z_datefirstuploaded is null then 1 else 0 end) as Number_not_uploaded,
       sum(case when quantityavailable > 1 and z_datefirstuploaded is null and dateoflastsale <= '2019-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) as Number_sitting
from icprod;
```

Notes that I changed the date constant to be ISO 8601 standard format.  In some databases, you may need to precede that with `date`.

This can in turn be simplified to:

```
select count(*) as Number_of_products,
       sum(case when discontinued = true then 1 else 0 end) as Number_of_discontinued,
       sum(case when z_datefirstuploaded is null then 1 else 0 end) as Number_not_uploaded,
       sum(case when z_datefirstuploaded is null and dateoflastsale <= '2019-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) as Number_sitting
from icprod
where quantityavailable > 1
```